# Angular: How to filter by deep object property in array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have an objects formatted like this:

```
id: 1,
name: MyObj
properties: {
  owners: [
  {
    name:owner1,
    location: loc1
  },
  {
    name:owner2,
    location: loc1
  }
 ]
}
```

Number of owners is different for each object. When I try to filter it using `ng-repeat` with `filter:searchBox` and search box inputs

```
<input name="search-filter" class="form-control" type="search" ng-model="searchBox.properties.title" />
<input name="search-filter" class="form-control" type="search" ng-model="searchBox.properties.owners" />
```

filtering by title works perfectly, however owners filtering doesn't work at all but I supposed it will filter based on both location and name. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what you wanted to search in owners object? `name` **OR** location

Comment: @PankajParkar I have another object like this one where owners are not nested in properties, and it works just fine on all owners parameters. However in that case when i try to filter by name or location specifically, i get nothing. I just can't figure out how to do it when owners array is nested. Seems like Angular only goes through a few nested properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.objs = 
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'MyObj',
    properties: {
      owners: [
      {
        name: 'owner1',
        location: 'loc1'
      },
      {
        name: 'owner2',
        location: 'loc2'
      }
     ]
    }
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<input name="search-filter" class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search by location" ng-model="searchBox.properties.location" />
<input name="search-filter" class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search by name"   ng-model="searchBox.properties.owners" />
 
  <div ng-repeat="owner in objs.properties.owners | filter:{'location': searchBox.properties.location} |filter:{'name': searchBox.properties.owners}">
    {{owner}}
    
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly in your snippet but doesn't work at all in my code >_<

Comment: How can I do that? It won't fit in the comment

Answer (score 0):

You can filter manually

```
var list = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'MyObj',
    properties: {
      owners: [
      {
        name: 'owner1',
        location: 'loc1'
      },
      {
        name: 'owner2',
        location: 'loc1'
      }
     ]
    }
  }
];

function filter(filter) {
  return list.filter(function(item) {
    return item.properties.owners.find(function(owner) {
      return Object.keys(filter).every(function(key) {
        return filter[key] === owner[key];
      });
    });
  });
}

console.log(filter({ name: 'owner1', location: 'loc1' }));
```

I used es6 shim for that.